# Unable to access variable inside closure swift

Tags: swift, firebase, closures

I'm trying to get my firebase database data into a variable to use it in my project

```
var someArray = [Array]()
let dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("SomeDatabase")


func loadSomeDatabaseData {
   dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
       let someDict = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
       let keysOfSomeDict = Array(someDict.keys)
       self.someArray.append(contentsOf: keysOfSomeDict)
       self.collectionView?.reloadData()
   }
}
```

I've tried calling loadSomeDatabaseData() in my viewDidload, followed by printing someArray, which results in an empty array. I know the keysOfSomeDict array has the correct data that I want, since i tried printing this array directly inside the closure. I would however also like to be able to print and use this data elsewhere in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase  `observeSingleEvent` method is `asynchronous` method. it executive in background only because it take time to fetch data from Firebase.

if you print array immediately means you get only empty array.

so print array once you get the data from Firebase. for that you can use `escaping closure`

Function Declaration:

```
  func loadSomeDatabaseData(resultArray : @escaping([Array])->()) {
       dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
           let someDict = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
           let keysOfSomeDict = Array(someDict.keys)
           self.someArray.append(contentsOf: keysOfSomeDict)
           resultArray(self.someArray)
       }
    }
```

Func Call:

```
self.loadSomeDatabaseData{(firebaseReposne) in
   print("FirebaseData" , firebaseReposne)  // Hope here you will get your firebase data.
     self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This worked, nice! I have one question however: why do you put [Array] after escaping? What does this refer to? It would not let me, but i put [String] instead, which worked.

Comment: both will be work, you declared variable as 'var someArray = [Array]()' like this know. so i pass data in same formate. so that i put [Array] in escaping closure

Answer (score 0):

The `observeSingleEvent` is asynchronous. So immediately printing `someArray` after calling `loadSomeDatabaseData` will result in an empty array. It takes sometime to retrieve the data from Firebase api.

To use this data elsewhere in the app, you could set a flag indicating the data is loaded or send a notification to inform the data is available.

Comment: I'm quite new to programming, could you please explain in simpler terms? I understand the fact that it is asynchronous and needs to wait but i don't understand how i do this in my project. I was hoping the collectionView.reloadData() method would fix this but it did not.

Comment: I have not tried populating the collectionview with the data from keysOfSomeDict as I assumed it would not work since it prints as an empty array. Currently I'm populating my collectionview with a plist with names and images of items. I'd like to achieve the same with firebase - the string of an item in my database should be displayed in the label of each collectionview cell.

Comment: If after loading the data from Firebase the closure is executed and the self.someArray.append(contentsOf: keysOfSomeDict) appends the result to someArray. You should be able to use someArray as the dataSource for the collection-view. So instead of using the plist, use someArray. Initially the collection view will not show any data, but when the closure is executed the collection view will reload with the data from the array.

Comment: This worked, thank you for the explanation! What had me confused was i assumed since it would print an empty array, the array would be empty no matter what, however it seems the array is not empty when using it in a collectionview because I'm calling the collectionview.reloaddata method which allows the closure to execute giving the array values if I've understood it correctly. But still, what if I'm not using the data from the closure to populate a collectionview which I can just reload, but I want to use the variable for something else? How would I do that?

Comment: Good to hear it worked. Just to clarify: the closure is executed asynchronous, so not immediately. Only after the data has been loaded from firebase. From that moment the data is loaded and you can use it, as in the above case by populating an array and reloading the view. Using the data without a collection view, implement a function on your view or view controller to process/display the data from the array. This function can then be called instead of the collection view reload function.